# MVC 6 application not releasing memory after view loaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc, memory, memory-management, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm running an MVC 6 application in Visual studio 2015 RC. When the application launches the memory usage levels out at about 100mb in debug mode.

[image: Memory usage low]

The problem occurs when I click any subsequent link and therefore load a view the memory usage rises and never falls, eventually leading to an out of memory exception. The below shows the memory usage after clicking a very simple contact page about 10 times over the course of a minute or so, each time the memory usage rises a bit and doesn't fall 10 mins later its still at 140mb.

[image: memory usage high]

Code for the contact page controller:

```
 public IActionResult Settings()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }
```

Code for the contact page view:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Contact";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

<address>
    One Microsoft Way<br />
    Redmond, WA 98052-6399<br />
    <abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr>
    425.555.0100
</address>

<address>
    <strong>Support:</strong>   <a href="mailto:Support@example.com">Support@example.com</a><br />
    <strong>Marketing:</strong> <a href="mailto:Marketing@example.com">Marketing@example.com</a>
</address>
```

This might not seem like a problem with a small view but when loading a listing page in my application the usage jumps significantly and after 5 or 6 page loads the application crashes with an out of memory exception.

I took a couple of snapshots of the memory usage and this is what's shown. Ive tried debugging to see where the memory spikes and it seems to be when the view is loaded.

[image: memory usage 3]

Has anyone experienced this with the new MVC projects? Is there a way to find out what is hogging the memory and release it? Apologies is this is something simple, I've been racking my brains trying to find out the problem!

Comment: MVC should be caching the rendered view which should cause memory to increase. This means after repeated executions of the same view memory should level out (after GCs and such) to a set amount.  Do you see memory constantly increasing for repeated execution of the same view after GCs?

Comment: Yes that's what happens, after repeatedly executing the same view the memory usage climbs and climbs until an out of memory exception occurs. I even tried manually calling the GC to clean up but this had no effect.

Comment: I would file a bug on MVC so it can be investigated. https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After posting an issue on the mvc github, the team reported that its the browser link functionality that's causing the problems.

If you remove app.UseBrowserLink(); from the Startup.cs class (line 99 in the default one) it will fix the problem and speed your application up a lot.

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2790